# PostgreSQL, importação de arquivo csv

Tags: postgresql, administração-postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

Estou tendo muitas dificuldade para tentar realizar a importação do arquivo CSV utilizando `PostgreSQL`, aparentemente o programa não está conseguindo realizar a leitura do arquivo, porém concedi permissão em todos usuários e pastas do sistema operacional e no programa em si.

Vi em alguns site para utilizar essa sintaxe, mas ela apresenta erro ao executar o comando.

```
psql\copy maquinas

from 'E:\Mídia\Cursos\SQL Server\Postgres\LogMaquinas.csv'

delimiter ','

csv header;
```

Segue mensagem que aparece ao tentar executar

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esse arquivo existe na pasta?

Comment: experimente trocar cada  `\ ` por duas `\\ ` no nome do arquivo: 'E:\\Mídia\\Cursos\\SQL Server\\Postgres\\LogMaquinas.csv'  - não consigo confirmar agora se é o caso do postgresql, mas muitas linguagens de programação reservam a `\ ` como um caractere de escape para colocar caracteres especiais na string. (inclusiv epara citar uma única `\ ` aqui no stackoverflow dá problema - preciso por um espaço junto)

Comment: Note que o sugerido é rodar o comando `\copy` do cliente `psql`, não me parece que esteja rodado o psql mas sim algum outro programa cliente. Creio que esteja rodando o comando `COPY` na máquina servidora e não na cliente https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html.

Comment: Como jsbueno comentou o manual, na documentação do comando SQL COPY, diz: "filename

    The path name of the input or output file. An input file name can be an absolute or relative path, but an output file name must be an absolute path. Windows users might need to use an E'' string and double any backslashes used in the path name.
"